# Custom viewing of files from Documents and Media portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have a requirement where in a drop-down with years (2008,2009,2010,2011,2012) as its values is to be displayed.

On select of a particular value all annual report (i.e all `pdf` files falling in that year) for that particular year are to be displayed.

I have found `Documents & Media` useful to store such files. I have created `Document Type` for annual report having following meta data:

1. **NAME:** Text field-name of the file uploaded
2. **FILE UPLOAD:** file uploaded
3. **YEAR:** Integer-this year are linked to the drop down values

I am trying a way to filter (displaying all years in drop down) be added on viewer.

When you select a year, the file document stored is displayed. Please help as how to go on further.

We have `Documents & Media Display` but it shows all the files
Or if `Web-content Display` can be useful?
Or if how `Documents & Media Display` can be modified to generate a drop-down of all values displaying links to the pdf?

Please help.

Comment: maybe you could look into the dynamicQueryAPI of liferay ([this link](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Queries+2%3A+DynamicQuery+API))

Answer (score 0):

So here is your requirement in short:

1. Show a drop-down with certain values
2. On select of any of the values, a list should appear which displays the list of files.

So here are my suggestions according to the points above:

1. Create your own custom portlet to show the drop-down. Don't go with customizing the liferay's portlet since later on you might get some more requirement to refine the logic or change the UI and you may also be required that Liferay's Document library portlet works as is. But if you want that uploading the files and a drop-down should be given in the same portlet then you have just one option to go with the Documents and Media display portlet.
2. Write your custom logic to display the list of files using [Liferay Document & Media API](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/service/DLAppServiceUtil.html) in conjunction with [Dynamic Query API](http://www.liferay.com/web/minhchau.dang/blog/-/blogs/3813353).

The challenge would be to make the logic of fetching files according to the `Meta-types` for your `Document Type`, since I don't think liferay does not provide any way to fetch data according to the Meta-data types in a `Document Type`.

Please comment if you need something more or have not understood anything.